# j3k0 cordova plugin purchase android transaction receipt is not updated

Tags: javascript, android, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to set up [j3k0 Plugin Purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) for subscriptions on Android and somewhat have it working.

- I register my products and then call store.refresh()
- On my products page I call store.get('my_id') and retrieve the products which I display
- On purchase I call store.order('my_id') which does initiate the billing popup.  I confirm and the first time everything appears fine
- I have store.when('my_id').approved(function(data) { my code in here }); which does get called and worked the first time.  Now every time I try to test it I get the same data.transaction back so I keep referencing the original receipt data which is cancelled when I try to validate on my server.

  ```
  store.when('my_id').approved(function(data) {
       var receiptIsAlwaysTheSame = data.transaction.receipt;
       //I send the receipt to my server here to validate
   });
  ```

I do get valid test emails from the store every time I subscribe or cancel so not quite sure why the transaction seems to be cached.  I did see this older issue with iOS on the GitHub site which just recently went on the backlog and not sure if it is similar or what: [Receipt Validation](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/121)

**UPDATE**

So after 3 days I made another purchase and the method gave me back a new valid receipt with new transaction data.  My first thought was the grace period on my product, but that is set to 0 days anyway.  So still not sure why I have to wait 3 days before making another purchase.  If anybody knows how to force this to refresh before then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to implement my own server for validating non-renewing subscriptions, in order that these can be restored on new app install etc.  I'd like to be able to do it without collecting a unique ID from the user e.g. email address. Is that possible?

Comment: First, I would ask that as a question on the site so you get more responses.  I am not 100% sure, but I assume you would need some type of unique ID to properly identify your users.